# How do I fix the new Xcode 10.1 Auto-indent behaviour?

Tags: xcode

After recently updating to Xcode 10.1, all new methods and indeed almost everything I add to a code file now gets indented by one extra tab space.

This is most annoying and wasting a lot of time. I object to this behaviour because it simply wastes screen space by a pointless tab width on the left of everything. The only thing it seems to allow at the left margin is properties and the first line of each method. As soon as you type a { character, though, everything after that is pointlessly indented.

This seems to be new behaviour, because I have not had this problem before. Can anyone shed light on why this has changed, whether it is useful or not, and hopefully a way to stop it?

I currently think it might be a bug/mistake, but I'm willing to learn if anybody can provide an explanation of why it might be a 'good thing'...

Currently, my only solution is to go to Preferences -> Text Editing on the Xcode menu and under the Indentation tab, simply disable 'Syntax-aware indenting' altogether. This is usually quite useful, so I would like to find a better solution. Also, this doesn't stop it from adding tabs when copying and pasting sections of code. No matter where in the file a chunk of code is pasted, it always gets an extra tab space before every line. I can't find any way to stop this.

**Example** (I normally use tabs for indents and set their width at 4 spaces)

This is how my code used to look:

```
- (void)myMethod: (NSString*)string {
    // Do something with a string
    NSLog(@"You gave me a string: %@", string);
}
```

But now it looks like this:

```
- (void)myMethod: (NSString*)string {
        // Do something with a string
        NSLog(@"You gave me a string: %@", string);
    }
```

**Update:**

I have a suspicion that this is due to new editor behaviour around the @implementation and @interface etc. directives. Everything within these sections seems to be forcibly indented by the editor now.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot and show the space you want to remove?

Comment: Xcode’s auto indent does get confused with C style `#ifdef` blocks. Even if it isn’t that it’s worth raising a Radar to try and get it fixed.

Comment: I've added an example of how this has changed my code layout.